# What determines the graphics of a device?

Tags: applications, settings, google-play-games, graphics

I do play a lot of games and most games settings have options to either set your graphics to low, average or high. So I'm really curious to find out what exactly determines the graphics of a phone so that I can set my game graphics according to what will work perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major hardware elements that determine what graphics quality you can choose are:

1. Graphics chip built into your main CPU. The faster it is and the more parallel computation cores it has the more calculations per second can be done
2. The maximum RAM of your device
3. The display resolution. The higher the resolution the more pixel have to be calculated -> the longer the calculation of each display frame takes -> the less frames per second can be displayed

Comment: Okay, what do you suggest for a   6.52 inch IPS Infinity-V Display, 720 x 1600 pixels, 20:9 aspect ratio (~269 ppi)Android 9.0 (Pie); HIOS 5.5 with 4GB RAM
Octa-core Mediatek MT6762 Helio P22 (12 nm)
64GB Built-in Storage with Memory Card

Comment: @Chinez MT6762 is a mid-class chip from 2018, hence I would assume you should choose mode average or low. Just test it out, start with the higher mode and if it stutters too much or the phone is getting too hot use the low mode. For older games with very simple graphics the high mode my be also usable, but that is game specific.